# Can boot from CD but not from DVD

Tags: linux, boot, bootable-media

I'm trying to install linux on an old Pentium IV computer currently running Windows 7.

I can't get it to boot to a live linux DVD. It does boot to CD rom if I put a bootable CD in there.

What causes this? What can I do to boot from DVD? I've tried booting from USB as well, but I don't think the BIOS can do that.

Comment: If the hardware is old enough to have a Pentium IV, it's possible the optical drive can't read DVDs. Are you sure it's a DVD/CD drive and not just a CD drive? Even if it supports DVDs, it might not support advanced formats like rewritable or double layer DVDs.

Comment: Download the [PLOP boot manager](https://download.plop.at/files/bootmngr/plpbt-5.0.15.zip) ZIP file. Extract the archive and burn the ISO to a blank CD. When booting from the CD, you will have to option to boot from USB even if the mobo doesn't support it natively.

Comment: @Arnon, It's definitely a DVD rewritable drive.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I use PLOP boot manager, it stops responding the moment I choose to boot from USB.

Comment: @ImperviousClarity Remember that you will need a USB drive that has an MBR boot sector on it (UEFI boot won't work), and also remember that whatever OS you put on needs to be 32-bit.

Comment: @ImperviousClarity **Also try starting PLOP before you insert the USB drive.** Once you insert it, highlight the USB option and hit SHIFT+ENTER

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the DVD drive was faulty. It could still read CD's, but no longer DVDs. I've replaced it with another second hand IDE DVD drive and now I can boot from DVDs.